# How are unused returned values handled in typed languages with type inference?

Tags: type-safety, type-systems

How do strongly typed languages that have type inference, handle the unused returned values (where it's not obvious what the intended type is)?

Here's an example where this happens in the untyped Python, where it's of course not caught:

```
list(map(lambda item: item.some_method, some_collection))
```

Here `item.some_method` was intended to be called, for its side effects, so the correct line is:

```
list(map(lambda item: item.some_method(), some_collection))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional constraints, a strongly-typed language with type inference will typically not prevent the first example, as it is technically valid, as you point out. There are a few ways this could be avoided.

1. You could explicitly annotate the type of the map (or use it somewhere that forces the type to be equal to something). This would result in a type checking error if the wrong variant is used.
2. Some languages (e.g. Rust) distinguish between `map` and `for_each`, where the latter is expected to be impure/effectful. If you use `for_each` in the first example, this would fail to compile, as the type of `lambda item: item.some_method` is `A -> () -> ()`, rather than `A -> ()`. However, nothing prevents you from unidiomatically using `map` here.
3. Some languages (e.g. Haskell) distinguish between impure/effectful values and pure/effectless values. In this setting, `map` would be expected to take a lambda that is pure (making `lambda item: item.some_method()` invalid) and `for_each` would be expected to take a lambda that is impure (making `lambda item: item.some_method` invalid). This is enforced using [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)), which act as a marker that tell the type system a value is impure (e.g. the type `IO(A)` represents an effectful `A` type).
4. Some languages (e.g. Rust) allow the use of values to be tracked and functions to be annotated to enforce their return values to be "used" in some way. If `map` is annotated `#[must_use]` in this way, then its return value must be used, which would alert you to an incorrect use of `lambda item: item.some_method` (as the return value of `map` would not be used). In Rust, the unit type `()` is automatically "used", and in theory this could be extended to include `[()]`, in which case the correct code `lambda item: item.some_method()` would work without issues.

Comment: I assume the language does type inference, so no explicit types are provided by the user. Using your notation, both `()->()` or `()` are valid types in this case, depending on what the map is supposed to return: `List[()->()]` or `List[()]`. The problem is that the returned value is unused. So I guess the language needs to somehow enforce the type of the returned value that is not used -- and I was wondering how it might do that. Let me change the title of my question to make this more clear.

Comment: @max: ah, I misinterpreted. I've updated my answer to hopefully answer the question as you intended.

Comment: It was my fault for asking a question in a very confusing way. Your original answer helped me see how to rephrase my question to match my intent. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: BTW, with C++, the unused values are typically just cast away with `(void)`, which of course does not solve the problem -- since both `List[()]` and `List[()->()]` would be cast away without warning. I suppose even in C++, one *could* assign the result of the map to a variable, specify the variable's type explicitly, and *then* cast it away to void. But it's so troublesome and noisy that I doubt anyone would do this.